# Is there a way to use the Authorize attribute with a request that does not have an authentication header?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, jwt, authorization

I am attempting to convert an API from using the authentication header for authentication to using a value in a JSON body for authentication. The requests I will be receiving from this point forward will not contain an authentication header. They will contain the bearer token in the body of the JSON request body. I was able to use the `OnMessageReceived` event handler to parse the token out, but I am receiving an Authorization Failed message in the output before I even hit the `OnMessageReceived` handler. It appears that it is failing authorization before going through the authentication handlers. As for the AuthorizeAttribute, I have tried both `[Authorize]` and `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]` without success.

I did not put any custom authorization policies in my setup.cs, so it is using the default one. After doing some research, I figured out that the only requirement on the default Authorization policy is `DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement`. I have included the requirement check code below:

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Makes a decision if authorization is allowed based on a specific requirement.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context">The authorization context.</param>
        /// <param name="requirement">The requirement to evaluate.</param>
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, 
                                                       DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement requirement)
        {
            var user = context.User;
            var userIsAnonymous =
                user?.Identity == null ||
                !user.Identities.Any(i => i.IsAuthenticated);
            if (!userIsAnonymous)
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

It seems to me that it automatically is failing if there is no Authorization header (which seems like it could be a bug). I tried adding an authorization header (with both a valid and an expired token) and putting a breakpoint in the `OnMessageReceived` handler. The result was a `HttpContext.User.Identity` (the only identity in identities) with a `IsAuthenticated` value of false. This matched the result of a request without an authorization header.

My question is whether it is possible to use the Authorize attribute in my scenario. If it is not, do I need to create an authorization filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was using `.AddIdentityServerAuthentication()` which is now obsolete according to IdentityServer (https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/4892). Switching to `.AddJwtBearer` fixed my issues. The authorization worked perfectly out of the box as it was supposed to.